# How to get specific number of posts from a particular post-type with pagination in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a post-type `grammer` and taxonomy named `subject`. There are almost 220 Posts in `grammer`.

Now i wish to retrieve only 25 posts from post-type `grammer` where `taxonomy => 'subject'` and it's slug value is `level-1-beginner`.

These results should paginate with only 1 post per page.

I tried using `WP_Query` but it seems I can't limit the total number of posts fetched.

```
$args = array (
'post_type'              => 'grammer',
'post_status'            => 'Published',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'subject',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'level-1-beginner'
    )
),
'pagination'             => false,
'paged'                  => '1',
'posts_per_page'         => '1',
'order'                  => 'ASC',
'orderby'                => 'rand');

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    echo the_content();

}
} else {
// no posts found
} ?>
<div class="tl-pagination"><?php wp_pagenavi(); ?></div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thansks.

Comment: `posts_per_page` really should limit your posts, if it's not then that means you're not viewing the correct template or not viewing the correct loop. Can you verify you're viewing the correct loop using the query you posted above?

Comment: yes, actually it is showing 1 post par page. But it is getting all 45 posts with terms "level-1-beginner" While I only want to get 25 posts and show 1 post per page.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying you only want 25 pages, even though there's 45 pages, correct? Can you edit your original question and add in your pagination code please?

Comment: yes I want to show 25 pages in total. using 1 post per page pagination.

Comment: just fyi, `post_status` should be `publish` not `Published`

Comment: // The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  $query->the_post();
  echo the_content();
  
 }
} else {
 // no posts found
} ?>
<div class="tl-pagination"><?php wp_pagenavi(); ?></div>

Comment: cannot see the Edit link of the question. Sorry

Comment: Edited the question. I am using pagenavi plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Paginate Links,](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) the code would look like this:

```
<?php if($query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Posts') ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('More Posts &raquo;', ($query->max_num_pages > 25) ? 25 : $query->max_num_pages) ?>
    <?php
            $big = 9999999999;
            $args = array(
                'base'          => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'format'        => '?paged=%#%',
                'current'       => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'total'         => ($query->max_num_pages > 25) ? 25 : $query->max_num_pages,
                'end_size'      => 0,
                'mid_size'      => 2,
                'prev_next'     => False
            ); 
            echo paginate_links($args); 
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The `total` parameter will limit the number of pages shown to 25. The [`next_posts_link()` Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) Also has a max number of pages parameter you can set.

You'll have to style the CSS to show which page is active. Each page number has 2 classes:

`page-numbers`  and if it's the current page: `current` so you'll need to style them accordingly.

Comment: This will limit the total number of posts in the Loop ?

Comment: Yup, it tests if there are pages and if the number of pages is greater than 25, stop it at 25 otherwise show all the pages.

Comment: Thankyou, one more thing. Next and previous links are not working properly. When I click Next and goes to second post it only shows me previous link and the page numbers. It wont show which page number I am on.

Comment: I've updated my answer, you'll need to style the current page number in css. You may need to use a dev tool such as firebug or chrome.